# How to give a SU privileges to an app

Tags: root-access

I change the custom ROM from CM to RR, but now some apps can't be granted with a root access. Even when i type "su" in the terminal no question is prompted to grand root access to the app. I have update the SU binaries to the latest version also, but this didn't help.

Comment: In a terminal, issue `su` and then `whoami`, and please do tell us the terminal's response.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled root access in developer settings?
Go to:

```
Settings > About phone
```

Then tap on the build number 7 times.
Afterwards, return to settings and enter

```
Developer settings
```

In dev settings you will find this option:

```
Root access
```

Click it and choose either apps or apps and adb depending on what you want to do.
I also use SuperSU for SuperUser rights management.

Comment: Yes i have enabled this, i know that in the CM based rom's this is feature in the Developer Setting's. Some apps have root access, but in some that i need and they support root access for example SD maid, when i use it there is no window from SU that prompt's to allow root access.. And the same is with the terminal emulator like i said later.

Comment: Do you use any SU rights manager?

Comment: Yes and i know how to use the SU app. But in this case i don't know from where is coming this problem.

Comment: Now the problem is gone..Maybe it was some error in the system itself.

Comment: Glad you somehow got it working

Comment: Does not work in Android 8